# How to write a tree structure to disk (VBA with no serialisation)

Tags: vba, serialization, tree, deserialization

So I am using VBA (not by choice) to do some fairly non trivial programming and finding it a nightmare. Normally I'd just use serialisation to dump the class/object to disk then read it back in but I cannot do that here, not unless I write my own serialisation function, which is basically what I am asking how to do here.

I have a class

```
[Node.cls]
Public pictureName As String
Public tagGroup As String

' Collection of Node objects
Public children As New Collection

Public isOverViewScreen As Boolean

' Collections of strings
Public overViewScreenWellNames As New Collection
Public overViewScreenWellType As New Collection
Public overViewScreenOpenPictureName As New Collection
```

which is basically a node in a tree structure, eg a node with a collection of child nodes which build a tree.

What would be the best way to dump this structure to a flat file and read it in, any hints?

I was thinking I could add a parent link to all of my nodes and just recursively visit the tree in order writing them to a txt file, then read it back in the same way, probably not the most efficient but I have a nice quad core machine here. Is there any simpler or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: i know this is old but just came across and wanted to leave a tip for any future visitor. You can create a Serializable class(dll library) in for example C# and add XML structure to represent the class(*nodes based*). You can then reference the library in VBA. Create an instance of the class and use the properties to set the class, properties, values. Expose a Serialize() method in your C# class and call it from VBA to serialize the class. Then restart Excel, create a new instance of your library and call DeSerialize() method to retrieve the instance. When Im free ill write a full solution.

Comment: Thank you that sounds like a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote a function that recursively visits the tree and dumps the 'nodes' to a flat text file, I then wrote a function that reads each node back in via a state machine that reads the node line by line recreating the tree, took too long, but it seems to work fine.

Thanks everyone who read it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I'm assuming a pre-order traversal + writing out the node did the trick for you.